# Too many questions are `on hold` in movies

Tags: discussion

my question was `onholded` too. But what I see on the first page, that now it happens to almost every question about `identify` of `plot exploration`

something wrong I guess.

Comment: Low quality question need to closed at all cost.

Comment: ok,. but here's the interesting question https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78644/sci-fi-thriller-about-memory-implant-chips and it's onholded too, for example

Comment: Read [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) then to know why question get closed

Comment: I understand about level requirements and so on, but if there's 90% of  `onholded` questions on the first page, then it seems like something wrong, and it's not because of questions

Comment: It's because of the falling quality of identification questions.

Comment: It is because of the questions. If they were **good** ID questions they wouldn't be on hold. For a good ID question see **this** one from just now - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/movie-about-a-bridge-accident-people-dying-horribly-and-premonition

Comment: About example I've given above. `If` OP doesn't remember other things about this movie? As for me there're enough details to identify this one

Comment: That's nice but **answerability** is not the same as **quality**. I'm certain that with a little effort the OP could recall a lot more. The language and whether it was animated to name two *easy* ones.

Comment: Note...it's about the **quality** of the question. Not whether it can be identified from one detail. That's what the "hold" notice says `"Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the site's quality standards." `

Comment: *"if there's 90% of onholded questions on the first page, then it seems like something wrong"* - Well, sure, indeed. But if *not* closing those bad questions is the correct approach is debatable.

Comment: If you find out the title of the movie nonetheless, you are still not supposed to give an answer? My comment to https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78693/a-girl-with-animal-ears-and-eyes was deleted.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Answers in comments are discouraged here, mainly because they undermine the quality-assurance processes. The desired order is 1) The questioner adds further details and improves the question by making an edit..2) The edited  question gets revised, and if it meets the quality standards, it gets reopened 3) Other user can post their answers (hopefully in good quality as well)

Answer (score 8):

> something wrong I guess.

## You are correct.

Questions are put on hold when they do not meet the standards we expect.

> "Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the site's quality standards."

This is our guidance on the "Hold" notice

---

This is particularly true of ID questions where a **high** level of detail is required.

The [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78644/sci-fi-thriller-about-memory-implant-chips) you linked in comments is missing **many** details that we would expect to see. In fact it only has *one* from many that could be provided.

Our [guidance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) lists just *some* of the details we would expect to see in a good question.

> - Plot details of any scenes you remember
> - Descriptions of any characters or locations
> - Where you watched the movie or TV show
> - When you watched the movie or TV show
> - Any idea of how old it was
> - Any idea of country of origin (if known)
> - Whether it was animated or not
> - Any other distinctive detail

Questions that are put on hold are given guidance on how they can be improved.

---

As for the current front page...**YES** today saw a raft of poor questions come in *but* they were all reviewed by other users and found wanting.